# "Combine" multiple processes

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, process, sandbox

I have an application that pops up a ton of processes in task manager (Chrome) and I want to know if there is a program that will wrap itself around them so that only one process is showing. Similar to a virtual machine in that only one process shows in task manager, but dissimilar in that it is not running an entire OS in it - just that app and it's "children".

Comment: Why are you looking at your process list so often that you find it annoying?

Comment: I have major ram issues, so task manager is  open whenever I am on Windows

Comment: Thinking that adding _more_ memory pressure, in the form of an entire virtual machine running a second operating system, is the answer to RAM shortage is entirely wrongheaded.

Comment: exactly why I don't want to use a VM, I was saying that that's the only thing that I could think of that would do what I am wanting.

Comment: This feature is not available and probably will never be (see [my comment here](http://superuser.com/a/720747/194694)). Any additional program that could possibly provide it will only make your RAM problems worse. The real problem is that you don't have enough RAM.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, pretending that I don't have RAM issues and that a VM is not an option, is there a program similar to Sandboxie in that it opens programs in it, but not in a separate process?

Comment: In other words: _Ignore the fact that I'm asking one of those "XY Questions". I'm re-spelling my assumption and asking about a "sandbox" instead of a "virtual machine"._ If you want to ask your question _correctly_ provide hard data in your question. Show your resident set sizes and your page fault rates. Show that you're even addressing your real problem. Don't assume the answer. Stop assuming that there's some magical "process combiner" that is the answer. The answer may not even involve Chrome at all. You've certainly not yet demonstrated to the world at large that it does, with numbers.

Comment: @JdeBP: 1. I never asked about a virtual box or sandbox in particular. All I said was "the only thing I can _think of_" 2. As I said in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/720745/combine-chrome-exes-into-one-process#comment923087_720747) I was looking for a 3rd party app. So no, the answer probably won't involve Chrome. I am revising my question to better fit what I am looking for.

Comment: Buy more RAM.  It's cheap these days.

Comment: @Timberwolf The tool that you're looking for will consume additional amount of RAM. You need it because many Chrome processes bother you. You see them because you are already low on RAM. Don't you see where your real problem is?

Comment: Ugh. I shouldn't have said anything about my RAM. I don't care about extra RAM consumption. I only want to save my Task Manager from displaying 20-40 chrome.exe's. I can deal with the tad bit extra RAM consumption I was forced to use Chrome because Firefox takes up 3.5 out of 3.8 GB. I don't like Chrome very much because of the interface but it is better then IE and it takes <2GB (possibly <1 as I can't tell with the 30 exe's showing) of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible. Maybe in the future, Google Chrome team would have all chrome.exe processes together into one.

There is a specific purpose for why every facet of Chrome is split into a different process. It's so that if one feature, extension, website etc. causes a crash, the entirety of Chrome won't stop working, just that single thread.

Comment: Which is why I am using Chrome, can't get Firefox to load long enough to put it in safe mode. But I was hoping for a 3rd party app that "sandboxes" it into one "virtual" process.

Comment: It's more than just crash handling improvement technique. Separate processes are the key to Chrome's sandboxing mechanism which is an important security feature. This said, I don't think Chrome team will ever decide to drop this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does a "[copy on write](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103858)" thing for virtual memory pages.  Pages of the `chrome.exe` process that are the actual executable, i.e. same amongst all the processes are not duplicated in RAM.

So even if what you wanted to do was possible, it wouldn't save you any more RAM.

Buy more RAM.

Comment: I'm not looking to save RAM, I'm looking to condense the process list on Task Manager.

Comment: Sysinternals' Process Explorer will collapse/expand process groups I think.

Comment: Well if I am going to go that route, I will just make my own...